# php_printer.dll not working

Tags: php, apache, dll, printing, wamp

hi guys i have been trying to set up printer for wamp but this error

**"Call to undefined function printer_open()"** shows when i run my script on wamp....................
My code is

```
<?php
$page = "ashdg";
print_page($page);


function print_page($page)
{
    $printer = "HP LaserJet Pro MFP M126nw"; 
    if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
    { 
       //$content = get_file_contents($page); 
       //printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
       //printer_write($ph, $content); 
       //printer_close($ph); 
       echo "yess";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo"couldnt connect";
    }
    //phpinfo();
}
?>
```

shows up i dont know what to do please help...

what i did till now after googling:

1. downloaded the zip from this
   [Link](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/printer/0.1.0-dev/)
   and this file 9/15/2013 12:14 PM88139 php_printer-0.1.0-dev-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip 
   and copied the files from the zip to this folder wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext php_printer.pdb and the php_printer.dll both of them
2. Added this line "extension=php_printer.dll" at the end in the php.ini which is in the php5.5.12 folder
3. checked phpinfo() for loaded module and found out no reference of a printer in the entire page

Comment: i used the other files as well from the given link ....i tried out the 64bit TS and NTS as i am using 64 bit version restarted the server reloaded the page but but no result....